# How to prove that the skeleton of a groupoid is the coproduct of groups?

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory

Is there always a morphism between two objects in a category? If so, shouldn't the skeleton of one groupoid be a single element?

edit------
The skeleton of a groupoid is represented as the $\sqcup_{x\in Iso(C)}BAut(x)$, where $BAut(x)$ is the category associated with $Aut(x)$, $Iso(C)$ is the isomorphism classes of the category $C$. Am I right to say that the coproduct is a category since it is the coproduct of categories. If true, are we considering this coproduct in the category of all categories? Can I instead consider it as the category associated with $\sqcup_{x\in Iso(C)}Aut(x)$?

Comment: No, there isn't always a morphism between two objects in a category. A "natural" example that arises in practice is the category of fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answers to your edit and yes, yes, and no. The inclusion of groups into categories does not preserve coproducts: the coproduct at the end of your edit would be the *free product* of groups, whose associated category in particular only has one object and is certainly connected. But the disjoint union is, well, *disjoint*. There aren't any morphisms between the different components. Thus being a coproduct of categories is vastly different from being a coproduct of groups: the latter is the best approximation to a disjoint union you can get when you insist on keeping just one object.

Answer (score 1):

No, the only obligation is to have an identity morphism for each objet.
But of course you can have a category with many objects and no morphisms between them. (Exept identities). This is the definition of a **discrete category**.